# SBT Multi project build with Java and Scala. How to aggregate tasks?

Tags: java, scala, sbt

I have an SBT multi-project build, with some scala projects and some java projects. I use different plugins for code coverage, static analysis etc for java vs scala. e.g. jacoco for coverage in java and scoverage for coverage in scala. There are other differences too.

I want to be able to run `sbt build` (or something similar) in the top level project, then have that delegate to each of the subprojects to actually perform the build. Then the java projects can call jacoco and the scala ones can call scoverage.

Or perhaps there is a different approach than delegation to allow the sub-project to define what tasks are run for its build? Any help greatly appreciated.

Comment: Well, it's supposed to work exactly like you say. What have you tried, and what didn't work as you expected? What happens if you run, let's say, `sbt test` in the root project folder?

Comment: So tasks such as `sbt test` work as expected. But I want to be able to un a different sequence of tasks for the different projects. 
e.g. for java
`; clean; findbugs; jacoco:cover; package`
for scala
`; clean; coverage; test; coverageReport; coverageOff; scapegoat`